# How to resize labels, buttons in WPF with respect to localization strings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, localization

My application supports localization as it supports for many countries. When we code in our project we normally code and test using English, when it comes to localization we face many issues. For example Suppose in the UI there are Three Buttons with `"Email"`, `"Internal - Email"` `"External - Email"`, we place all this buttons inside a Grid and position this perfectly, its aligned and it looks good in the UI, but the same text strings in Portuguese and and in other localization strings does not fit in the said width and height of the UI control. And the UI looks ugly and facing many issues for different localization settings adjusting the height and width of the individual control.
In French `Email` is `Adresse électronique` nad its a problem to fit if we have a fixed size Button.

I want to know is there any way to resize the Height and Width of the Controls at run time based upon the localizations strings text length? I have noticed that link of `Automatic Layout and Controls` in MSDN but it does not help in how to implement that.

Can anybody help in this regard.

Thanks
Deb

Comment: The absolute simplest way is to *not* set any `Width` values on the `TextBlock` elements (or their container controls)... in this way, they are free to grow or shrink as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use grid, you could set horizontal/vertical align to "Strech" and specifie margin and padding. This should allow more flexibility.

Beside, being french, "email" or "mail" is much more common than "adresse électronique".
If you want a formal french word "courriel" is also a common shorter alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you'll have to take into account.  The first is not to specifically set the width of the control that displays the text (TextBlock Label) and the second is to not set a fixed width on the column of the Grid in which they are placed (use Auto or *).